# Passing Parameter List to Auto.Arima

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

In the "Failed Attempt" below I'm trying to pass a list of parameter values to auto.arima like the "Working Correctly" example. In the "Failed Attempt" auto.arima seems to ignore all the other values except tsdat1.

```
Code:
Tlambda <- 0.9999588

##Working Correctly
fit <- auto.arima(tsdat1, lambda = Tlambda, stepwise=TRUE, approximation = TRUE )

##Failed attempt
Param_List<-c(tsdat1, lambda = Tlambda, stepwise=TRUE, approximation = TRUE)
fit2 <- auto.arima(Param_List)



Data:

dput(tsdat1)
c(0.767202484266145, 2.96949977928183, 2.0671481782824, 3.66022236827445, 
1.01872427624301, 0, 4.45424966892274, 2.75619757104319, 1.83011118413722, 
1.01872427624301, 1.53440496853229, 1.48474988964091, 0, 1.83011118413722, 
2.03744855248601, 0, 1.48474988964091, 0.689049392760799, 1.83011118413722, 
0, 3.06880993706458, 0, 1.3780987855216, 1.83011118413722, 0, 
0.767202484266145, 4.45424966892274, 0.689049392760799, 3.66022236827445, 
1.01872427624301, 3.06880993706458, 1.48474988964091, 1.3780987855216, 
0, 4.07489710497203, 1.53440496853229, 4.45424966892274, 2.0671481782824, 
16.471000657235, 1.01872427624301, 3.06880993706458, 10.3932492274864, 
6.89049392760799, 3.66022236827445, 3.05617282872902, 0.767202484266145, 
4.45424966892274, 4.82334574932559, 7.32044473654889, 5.09362138121504, 
0.767202484266145, 10.3932492274864, 3.44524696380399, 9.15055592068612, 
7.13106993370105, 3.06880993706458, 10.3932492274864, 1.3780987855216, 
3.66022236827445, 7.13106993370105, 1.53440496853229, 5.93899955856366, 
4.13429635656479, 9.15055592068612, 6.11234565745804, 0.767202484266145, 
4.45424966892274, 2.0671481782824, 3.66022236827445, 5.09362138121504, 
3.83601242133072, 4.45424966892274, 2.0671481782824, 7.32044473654889, 
7.13106993370105, 4.60321490559687, 7.42374944820457, 6.20144453484719, 
7.32044473654889, 4.07489710497203, 1.53440496853229, 5.93899955856366, 
2.75619757104319, 5.49033355241167, 4.07489710497203, 1.53440496853229, 
5.93899955856366, 1.3780987855216, 1.83011118413722, 5.09362138121504, 
1.53440496853229, 2.96949977928183, 2.0671481782824, 7.32044473654889, 
3.05617282872902, 2.30160745279843, 8.90849933784549, 0, 3.66022236827445, 
1.01872427624301)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass arguments as a list, use `do.call`.

```
Param_List <- list(y=tsdat1, lambda = Tlambda, stepwise=TRUE, approximation = TRUE)
fit2 <- do.call(auto.arima, args=Param_List)
```

Comment: @Rob Hyndman   Thank you for getting back to me, that did the trick.  My end goal is to parallelize training multiple auto.arima models on different sets of cores.  So I'm trying to pass lists of parameters to parLapply, from the parallel package.  Do you have any tips on running multiple auto.arima forecasts in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
  Param_List<-list(x=tsdat1, lambda = Tlambda, stepwise=TRUE, approximation = TRUE)
  fit2 <- auto.arima(x=Param_List$x, lambda = Param_List$lambda, stepwise=Param_List$stepwise, approximation = Param_List$approximation)
```

I dont know if a more pretty solution exists, though